# My reputation is down to 1

Tags: support, user-accounts

Mods: please move this question to Meta.

I just logged on from a new system and my reputation is down to 1 (used to be over 5k). What is going on?

**Edit I**: After posting I also note that a different user name is showing up associated with this question.

**Edit II**: my profile is completely clean, it seems a fresh new account was associated with my email address.

**Edit III**: [my old profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/177437/lu%c3%ads-de-sousa) still exists. However, every time I log on I end up in this new account.

**Edit IV**: The problem has been solved. When I log on I am now directed to the original account.

Comment: Probably you created a new account instead of logging in to your old one? What was your old user account name or ID? Can you add a link to your old profile?

Comment: Make sure you are using the same email address as you used with your previous account.

Comment: I am using the same e-mail account as before. This is the e-mail account on which I recieve the digests and other messages from AU.

Answer (score 7):

Obviously, there are only certain things I can help you with directly and Stack Exchange will only help you if you can prove *you* own the main account. Just saying it's you isn't enough. I can give you some clues though.

The Stack Exchange OpenID this account is associated with is not the same one as that on your other account. That's why you keep ending up in this one. Your main account has a couple of login options associated with it: Another email account (different domain) and Launchpad.

Use one of those and when you have managed to log in there, you can request (if you need it) that this account be merged into that.

Comment: Thank you for the tips Oli. I should have only one e-mail address associated with my AU account. Launchpad is a good idea, but if I try to log on with my Lauchpad ID, AU informs me it will create a new account.